# Touch is not working with Unity UI Toolkit buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui, ui-toolkit

I'm having a weird issue, may be a simple fix.

I've got a UI only "game" using the new ***UI Toolkit***. It's a little kind of a drawing program. I've got a draw area in the middle with "tool buttons" on the sides. Everything works fine with Mouse, Pen, and touch when drawing (using scripts I can access all types of pointers), but for some reason touch doesn't work with the UI buttons only.

What's even weirder is that touch on UI buttons works when testing directly in Unity Play mode (I've got a touch screen laptop), but doesn't work when I make a Build.

In my Project Settings -> Input System Package, I've got Pen, Mouse, and Touchscreen active under "Supported Devices"

The new UI Toolkit is so new there's no help or similar issues I can find online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up since I ended up finding my answer somewhere else.

In the "Input System UI Input Module" component in the EventSystem, I changed the "pointer Behavior" to "Single Unified Pointer" and that fixed it. Not sure if that's just a work-around, but it works great now.

Answer (score 1):

if its still relevant:
I had the same issue and used "Standalone Input Module" instead of "Input System UI Input Module" in EventSystem. It says it's the old option, but it works for me :D

Comment: Thanks. This option won't work for me as I need to use the new input. Still haven't found a solution. Unfortunately, I just made it so my app needs to use a pen or mouse. Touch is not supported until I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I add the touch screen here and it works now.
[image]